# Implementing Lua for C#

Tags: c#, lua

I've built a robust system that has many core functions that might actually get mess to use if I keep on expanding the code - therefore I decided to implement a scripting language and ability for program to read scripts from external files.

My first idea was to use C# by default, but then I've remembered how easy and readable Lua was, so I went with that - sadly, I can't find a simple yet effective library that would allow me to incorporate lua into my software.

**tl;dr** — is there a simple library one could use to implement lua and thus make usage of software built-in functions way easier? What are your thoughts and opinions on that?

Comment: There is [NLua](http://nlua.org/) and there is [MoonSharp](http://www.moonsharp.org/). I do prefer NLua, [see my comment below on why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287905/implementing-lua-for-c-sharp#comment77538503_45287996).

Comment: use javascript. I went through exactly the same thing, everybody went 'what the heck is LUA?' (or TCL which I also tried). Nobody says that about javascript. And there are several good c# js engines. I use Jint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's [MoonSharp](http://www.moonsharp.org/).

I did experiments with it a while ago. Ultimately, I found it unsuitable for my needs, but it was straightforward to make use of.

Edit: dug up [my GitHub repo where I tried this out](https://github.com/hakelimopu/MoonSharpFollies/tree/master/Sandbox/Sandbox).

Comment: I've decided against MoonSharp and used [NLua](http://nlua.org/) instead. I do think NLua is more mature, more often updated and more popular. Just compare [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=moonsharp) to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nlua).

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for rapid response.